# opposite of memory-backed file?

Tags: android, linux, file-io, operating-system, mmap

Memory-backed file allows application to treat file as if it were primary memory. 
I am wondering if there is a similar mechanism in Linux which allows me to access a range of memory as if it were a file, i.e, through file path and read() write() system calls.

If it matters, I want to run Android emulator with system.img and userdata.img in memory to speed it up. So if anyone could tell me how to tell android-qemu to mount to a different (in-memory) partition, that would work too.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a `memory mapped` file?

Comment: No. memory mapped file is accessed as if it were memory, but I want to access memory as if it were file

Comment: RAM disks are that thing pretty much.

Comment: actually you want memfd, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html (keep in mind it's a relatively new interface)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want tmpfs

http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt

Comment: I guess if I want physical memory, I will need ramfs or ramdisk. But your answer really pointed me where to look for.

Comment: ramfs has to be used with care - you can easily exhaust all your RAM and kill the host. tmpfs will keep the file (or the bits you work on most, anyway) in RAM as long as you're actively using it, but you may occasionally pay the penalty of a page fault to retrieve it from disk if you left it alone for a bit or something with a higher priority needed physical RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can open `/proc/<pid>/mem` to access the memory of any process...

Comment: Let me clarify here. I do not want to access any process's virtual address space, I want to assign a range of physical memory which an application views as a file, and read/write call on this "file" is translated into memory access, so that I can get fast I/O

Comment: But this answer helps too. Now at least I know if OS doesn't support this, I could just go ahead and copy /proid/pid code and implement it myself.